# How do I prevent IE from breaking when passing Console to IIFE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iife

I have a script which needs to work in IE browsers < v11. Don't ask me why! It seems the console object is not available when IE does not have developer tools running and this causes problems.

I can't find a way of preventing the script from failing other than writing messy checks for undefined.

Here is some sample code using an IIFE:

```
  var vm = (function ($, c, opts) {

  }(jQuery, console, window.MyAppSettings));
```

I can't even test for undefined inside the IIFE as this seems to break before it is called. Is there any convention for this sort of thing?

Comment: What exactly does break? Do you get any error message?

Comment: The problem is console exists when debugging in IE the problem doesn't occur.  I just know the code breaks without the debugging tools, and so I suspect a javascript syntax error related to console being 'undefined'.

Comment: Then go for good ol' `try { … } catch(e) { alert(e); }` if you cannot open any console or error log. No, it certainly isn't a syntax error.